# How to compare the difference between two date and get it in hours?

Tags: python, pandas

I want check if the difference between the date of column `DHR_COL` and `DHR_TRANSF1` is more than 20 hours.

I did the calculation below to get this difference, but I cannot get in hours to compare with my limit (20 hours)

```
df["Transf1-Coleta"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DHR_TRANSF1"], format=("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))-pd.to_datetime(df["DHR_COL"], format=("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

In [21]: df

Out[21]:

```
              DHR_TRANSF1              DHR_COL           Transf1-Coleta
0          2021-07-14 15:00:00    2021-07-14 03:25:00    0 days 11:35:00
4          2021-07-14 23:59:00    2021-07-14 13:30:00    0 days 10:29:00
5          2021-07-15 00:16:00    2021-07-19 00:00:00   -4 days +00:16:00
8          2021-07-15 05:30:00    2021-07-14 17:00:00    0 days 12:30:00
9          2021-07-14 09:29:41    2021-07-14 17:00:00   -1 days +16:29:41
```

I thought about doing something like that, but it didn't work.How can I made it?

```
pd.to_datetime(df["Transf1-Coleta"] > "20:00:00")
```

Comment: You have to convert your "20:00:00", which is only a string, to a datetime object.

Comment: @RufusVS close... but no cigar. It should be a Timedelta. Comparing a difference in time with a point in time makes no sense.

Comment: If that point in time is based on time 0, it can be used as a delta, in my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the rows where the difference is bigger than 20 hours:

```
df[df["Transf1-Coleta"] > pd.Timedelta(hours=20)]
# or closer to your original try:
df[df["Transf1-Coleta"] > pd.Timedelta("20:00:00")]
```